# Android: EditText.setInputType() how to setup for email but not auto-suggest

Tags: android

I am using an `EditText` box for user to enter their email address.

I set it up using:

```
box.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS );
```

This results in the soft keyboard popping up with the '@' and '.' (and some keyboards '.com') keys on the initial keyboard layout.  Great just what I want.

However, I notice the text is all black (when I specified white).  I found this is due to auto-suggest.  If I go into `Settings->Languages/Keyboards->Touch Input->TextInput` and disable Prediction and Word Completion, then the text shows up white.

Now the question:  How do I get auto-complete programmatically disabled for this?

I have tried setting up the box by doing:

```
box.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS );
```

This results in all white text (i.e. no auto-suggest).  But then I longer have email '@' and '.com' buttons!  Bah-humbug.

Anyway to get both?   Thanks.

Comment: why no suggestions?

Answer (score 39):

This code should do the trick:

```
box.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS );
```

You can add as many flags as you want, as long as they're compatible with each other.

Comment: Thanks -- forgot to mention that I had tried that one. I also expected this would work.  It seems that auto-suggest is still on, even with the NO_SUGGESTIONS flag in this case.

Comment: What device version are you testing on? Are you on the emulator or an actual device?

Comment: Droid Incredible 2 on Android 2.3.4.

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest--on Android 2.3.6 (N1), the above code works. When you use these 3 flags, what is the result? Black text? Or no `@.`?

Comment: Black text.  Thanks for trying... seems to work fine on ICS as well.